# Installing pywafo getting "<name> is not a supported wheel on this platform"

Tags: python, pip

I've tried to install [pywafo](https://github.com/wafo-project/pywafo):

```
apt-get install gfortran
git clone https://github.com/wafo-project/pywafo.git
cd pywafo/
python3 setup.py bdist_wheel -d dist
pip3 install dist/wafo-0.3.1.post0.dev41+gea2edc1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
```

But I am getting:

```
$ pip3 install dist/wafo-0.3.1.post0.dev41+gea2edc1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl 
wafo-0.3.1.post0.dev41+gea2edc1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl is not
a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Not sure why this is the case. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you solve your installation issue?

Comment: @andrew Hi! I didn't have time yet to check out your solution. But I will do so next week and let you know if it worked! Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `dist/wafo-0.3.1.post0.dev41+gea2edc1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl` the `cp27` means CPython version 2.7. It looks like you are using Python 3.x. You either need to use a Python 2.7 virtualenv or find the `cp3x` version of that .whl.

Comment: Hi! Seems this was my fault. I was using the Python 2 compiler accidentally and cheated as I modified my question. Using Python 3 I am now getting a `wafo-0.3.1.post0.dev41+gea2edc1-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl`. However, now I am getting `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'llvm-config'`. Is there a chance you know why I need LLVM for pywafo?

Comment: This is a different issue. Sounds like an issue with installing Python Numba, it looks like you can use Conda to work around that. Not sure past that